# Link rel-alternate for blog feed

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, blog

This is a question asked in a blog comment by David Eppstein.

> Is there a reason for not having a “link rel=alternate” pointer to the feed? Yes, there’s a “Subscribe via RSS” link on the page, visible to humans, but the link rel syntax allows software to figure out where the feed is given only the url to the blog itself.

I don't know the answer.  Could someone clarify this, please, and add the feature if appropriate?

Comment: If it helps, this requested feature is called the RSS autodiscovery.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff, this [seems to require a modification](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-setup-auto-discovery-for-your-wordpress-rss-feeds/) to the header.php file/theme. Could you please ask Jin to add it to our theme? @Tsuyoshi Ito, thank you.

Comment: @Kaveh, you know that didn't actually alert me...right? (:  (and only @lerted Tsuyoshi because it couldn't alert me)

Comment: @Rebecca, no, I didn't know. I thought that should work, can you explain why it doesn't work so I avoid doing the same thing in future? (Thanks for activating RSS autodiscovery :)

Comment: @Kaveh, read the commenting (the "help" link underneath the add comment button) or the full details at http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting.

Comment: @Rebecca: I see. By the way, did you see my message about enabling [mcrypt](http://us3.php.net/mcrypt) module on the blog (for hiding emails addresses with reCHAPTCHA), [OpenId](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/), [OpenId commenting](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comments-with-openid/), and also support for threaded commenting? :)

Comment: @Kaveh, please put feature requests in their own post, not in comments.  Also, explain *why* these features would be useful. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out.  I wondered why the rss to the home url wasn't working! (;

Added, should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Rebecca!